# What is wrong with this custom "path finding" algo?

Tags: java, android, recursion, 2d, path-finding

(I hope this is not a duplicate as the many questions I came into do not fit my need)

I'm developping a 2D grid based game with 2 players with grid. There are two players: blue and red, each one places a stone in cells. So I want to find a path passing throught all cells with the same color back to the starting point, BUT ONLY if there is at least ONE cell that contains opponent's stone.

[image: Gameboard with some stones]

From the screenshot above: The red stones here in the upper right do not form a valid path. And those in the center are not forming a path neither even though that should be one.

I'm able to find a path but it is somehow broken, it doesn't work as expected.

EDIT:
**Pather class**

```
public class Pather {

    private static final int MIN_PATH_LENGTH = 3;

    public enum Neighbor{
        UP_RIGHT(0,1,-1),
        RIGHT(1,1,0),
        DOWN_RIGHT(2,1,1),
        DOWN(3,0,1),
        DOWN_LEFT(4,-1,1),
        LEFT(5,-1,0),
        UP_LEFT(6,-1,-1),
        UP(7,0,-1);

        public int index, x, y;

        Neighbor(int index, int x, int y){
            this.index = index;
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }

    }

    private static Neighbor[] neighbors = Neighbor.values();

    public static ArrayList<Path> findPaths(Stone[][] gameBoard){
        ArrayList<Path> paths = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Point> checkedPoints = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < gameBoard.length ; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < gameBoard[0].length; j++) {
                if(gameBoard[i][j] != null){
                    //set the origin of a potential new path
                    ArrayList<Point> potentialPath = new ArrayList<>();
                    Point origin = new Point (i,j);
                    if(!checkedPoints.contains(origin)) {
                        potentialPath.add(origin);
                        checkedPoints.add(origin);
                        potentialPath = findPath(gameBoard, i, j, potentialPath, gameBoard[i][j].getPaint(), checkedPoints, Neighbor.RIGHT.index); //Changed from Neighbor.DOWN.index
                            if (potentialPath != null) {
                                paths.add(new Path(potentialPath, gameBoard[i][j].getPaint()));

                            }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return paths;
    }

    private static ArrayList<Point> findPath(Stone[][] gameBoard, int x, int y, ArrayList<Point> path, Paint color, ArrayList<Point> checkedPoints, int cameFrom){

        int startClockwiseScanAtDirection = cameFrom + 5;
        for (int i = startClockwiseScanAtDirection; i < startClockwiseScanAtDirection + 7; i++) {
            // avoid ArrayIndexOutOfBounds
            if(x+neighbors[i%8].x < 0 || y+neighbors[i%8].y < 0 || x+neighbors[i%8].x >= gameBoard.length || y+neighbors[i%8].y >= gameBoard[0].length)
                continue;
            // check if there's a stone that matches the current stone, we're scanning around
            if(gameBoard[x+neighbors[i%8].x][y+neighbors[i%8].y] != null && gameBoard[x+neighbors[i%8].x][y+neighbors[i%8].y].getPaint() == color){

                // found one
                Point nextStone = new Point(x+neighbors[i%8].x,y+neighbors[i%8].y);

                // is the point we just found the origin of the path?
                if(nextStone.equals(path.get(0)) && path.size() > MIN_PATH_LENGTH) { //This seems to prevent drawing a path when we have less stone to form a path with
                    path.add(nextStone);
                    checkedPoints.add(nextStone);
                    return path;
                }
                // otherwise if it's already part of the path ignore it
                if (path.contains(nextStone)) {
                    continue;
                }
                // else add it to the path and keep going
                path.add(nextStone);
                checkedPoints.add(nextStone);

                // recurse on the next stone in the path
                ArrayList<Point> newPath = findPath(gameBoard,x+neighbors[i%8].x, y+neighbors[i%8].y, path, color,  checkedPoints, i%8);
                if (newPath == null){
                    // didn't find a way to continue, so backtrack
                    path.remove(path.size()-1);
                } else {
                    // we have a completed path to return
                    return newPath;
                }

            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Path class**

```
public class Path {
    public Paint getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(Paint color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public ArrayList<Point> getCoordinateList() {
        return coordinateList;
    }

    public void setCoordinateList(ArrayList<Point> coordinateList) {
        this.coordinateList = coordinateList;
    }

    private ArrayList<Point> coordinateList;
    private Paint color;

    public Path(ArrayList<Point> coordinatePath, Paint color){
        this.coordinateList = coordinatePath;
        this.color = color;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return coordinateList.toString();
    }
}
```

Here some case test:

Called in the MainActivity's onCreate():

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    gameGrid = findViewById(R.id.gameGrid);

    bluePaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    bluePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
    bluePaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);

    redPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    redPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    redPaint.setColor(Color.RED);

    bgrBluePaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    bgrBluePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    bgrBluePaint.setStrokeWidth(bgrStrokeWdth);
    bgrBluePaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);

    bgrRedPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    bgrRedPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    bgrRedPaint.setStrokeWidth(bgrStrokeWdth);
    bgrRedPaint.setColor(Color.RED);

    bluePlayer = new Stone(1,bluePaint, bgrBluePaint);
    redPlayer = new Stone(2, redPaint, bgrRedPaint);
    gameBoard = new Stone[100][100];

    gameBoard[47][47]= redPlayer;
    gameBoard[46][47]= bluePlayer;
    gameBoard[44][48]= redPlayer; //REDs form a path when you place this stone in the last positioon
    gameBoard[44][49]= redPlayer;
    gameBoard[45][47]= redPlayer;
    gameBoard[45][48]= bluePlayer;
    gameBoard[45][49]= bluePlayer;
    gameBoard[45][50]= redPlayer;
    gameBoard[46][50]= bluePlayer;
    gameBoard[46][49]= redPlayer;
    gameBoard[46][48]= redPlayer;
    gameBoard[47][50]= bluePlayer;
    gameBoard[47][48]= bluePlayer;
    gameBoard[47][49]= redPlayer;
    gameBoard[48][50]= redPlayer;
    gameBoard[48][49]= redPlayer;
    gameBoard[48][48]= redPlayer;
    gameBoard[49][50]= bluePlayer;
    gameBoard[48][51]= redPlayer;
    gameBoard[44][50] = bluePlayer;


    ArrayList<Path> paths = Pather.findPaths(gameBoard);
    gameGrid.setPaths(paths);

    gameGrid.setGameBoard(gameBoard);

}
```

Placing stones at the following positions clears the path:

```
 //Adding the following deletes the path
    gameBoard[43][50] = redPlayer; //Adding this one in last position clears the path
    gameBoard[45][51] = redPlayer;
```

I need to figure out how to make a condition that check for an opponent nearby first then validate the path.

EDIT 2:

Stone.java

```
public class Stone{

private int _player;
private Paint _paint, _bgrPaint;

public Stone(int player, Paint paint, Paint bgrPaint){
    _player = player;
    _paint = paint;
    _bgrPaint = bgrPaint;
}


public int getPlayer() {
    return _player;
}

public Paint getPaint() {
    return _paint;
}

public Paint get_bgrPaint() {
    return _bgrPaint;
}
}
```

Point.java

```
public class Point {
int x, y;

public Point(int x, int y){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}
@Override
public boolean equals(Object point) {
    return this.x == ((Point) point).x && this.y == ((Point) point).y;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "("+x+","+y+")";
}
}
```

Screenshoot of what a valid path should look

[image: Exemple]

Comment: Thanks down-voters, hope you never being in situations like this! If the question doesn't fit at any point what this comunity is aboout, just let me know and I'll correct it instead of down-voting as if it worth not being asked or doesn't have any interrest. You feel powerful doing that don't you.

Comment: I think the reason people are downvoting is because they think this might be regarding homework instead of a personal project. Not sure though - I don't do Java and can't help, sorry.

Comment: I don't think a homework may look like this! This is a personnal project I'm being working on several months! And I don't ask people do write code for me but I need their help to see what i'm not seing, a third person advice always helps! Most part is done onlly this algo is broken and I need help to figure out

Comment: @Krul please don't spend time complaining about votes; downvotes don't have to be justified any more than upvotes. That being said, it was probably because you didn't really clarify what your question was. You indicate that you're aware of some problems with your code and apparently you're not getting the output you expect, however you don't actually specify either.

Comment: Note that the distinction of "homework" vs "personal project" isn't really that relevant; what matters is whether or not it fits what's outlined as on topic on the help site (which this would probably fit once cleaned up) and the overall quality of the question (right now this reads like a "there's a bug somewhere in this pile of code, find it for me please" type question which aren't off topic, but rarely have interesting answers)

Comment: Okay, I may understand that one can find my question a bit unlear as I seem to be asking what I'm already awre of, I apologize. Some (shy) people (like myself) are not good at asking exactly what they need. However, I have two preocccupations in my question: (1) How to make it detect an opponent nearby then form a path and (2) Why it doesn't form path when a valid on is found

Comment: To make it more of a [mcve] please add hard coded **simple** `Stone[][] gameBoard` data which fails and `Stone` class as wel as `Path` and neighbors

Comment: That's alot of code to put here. That's why I wanted you to have a discussion on Discord

Comment: Please minimize to make it Mcve

Comment: I think I'm not able to minimize it as the whole app would break. @c0der

Comment: Without [mcve] one can offer only general direction and information like @Gene offered. If you want more specific debugging help you should provide comprehensive information so one can understand your code (and wont have to guess, for example, how `neighbors` is defined)  and run it. [Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @c0der UPATED, I hope I provided what you asked me to.

Comment: I think, to really reproduce the problem, you'll need to create a whole android app and create the the custom view with grid, cells, circle, and lines that are drawn upon paths

Comment: I find [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) a very useful technique. Not only it makes helping much easier, it 
is a powerful debugging tool. It many case, while preparing one, you are likely to find the problem.

Comment: The problem here is I don't seem to find a way to minimize all this without breaking it.

Comment: So how do you want others to run and test it ? You ask about down-votes - I think it is clear that essential information is missing.

Comment: Fine then. I'm going to recreate a minimal app. However, with the code above, one can reproduce what I described.

Answer (score 1):

A more-or-less standard way to approach this kind of problem is a "sweep line" algorithm. For simplicity, say we're looking for blue paths wrapping red points. 
(You can process red paths wrapping blue points at the same time or in a second pass, but you can work that out later.)

You can search for "sweep line algorithm" to see how they work in related applications.  The [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sweep_line_algorithm) isn't bad.

For this problem, the sweep line is a set of y-intervals. It's initialized using the leftmost (least x) blue point(s). It gets one interval for each vertically adjacent set of blue points. Each interval represents a vertical slice through a potential blue polygon.

The rest of the algorithm is to design the rules needed to update the scan line when it is moved one position to the right, incrementing x. This will be a matter of updating each interval. When a step finds a disconnected set of vertically adjacent points, a new interval is added. In some cases, intervals will "die out" because the potential polygon boundary dead-ends (think of a C shape). In other cases, they will "merge" because, at the corresponding x-coordinate, there is a set of 1 or more vertically adjacent connecting points. In still other cases, the polygon will complete successfully with a final set of 1 or more vertically adjacent points.

The details will be fiddly, but not hard to work out by case analysis.

To trace successful polygons, intervals can include two chains of preceding points: the upper and lower polygon boundaries.

The last consideration is whether a successfully closed polygon encloses at least one red point.  But this is easy. If for any x-coordinate, the interval representing a polygon bracketed a red point, then the answer is yes. This can be recorded as an initially false boolean maintained in the interval, which is set true every time such a red point is seen. When a polygon is successfully closed, check the flag to see whether it should be used or not.

All the above can be made efficient for very large grids by using suitable data structures: interval trees for example. But if the grid is comparatively small, it should be fine to use simple lists. At any rate, consider prototyping it with a list for the sweep line first first and optimize with more complicated data structures later if needed.

Comment: What do you think about a different approach: check, for each "stone", if it is surrounded by continuous  chain of stones from the opposite color.  I think it can be done using breadth first search starting from the stone in question.

Answer (score 1):

As I wrote in my comments, without mvce it is very hard to offer detailed help. 
From what I see in the code I figure you are trying to map all cyclic single-color paths on the board. 
I made some documented changes in the code, hoping (without being able to properly check it) that it may help you improve your code. 
Note that as `Stone` class was not posted, I changed the representation of the board to `int[][]`

```
import java.awt.Point;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

public class Phather {

    private static final int RED = 2, BLUE = 1;
    private static final int MIN_PATH_LENGTH = 3;

    public enum Neighbor{
        UP_RIGHT  ( 1,-1),
        RIGHT     ( 1, 0),
        DOWN_RIGHT( 1, 1),
        DOWN      ( 0, 1),
        DOWN_LEFT (-1, 1),
        LEFT      (-1, 0),
        UP_LEFT   (-1,-1),
        UP        ( 0,-1);

        int x, y;

        Neighbor(int x, int y){

            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }
    }

    public static Set<Path> findPaths(int[][] gameBoard){

        //use set to prevent duplicate paths
        Set<Path> paths = new HashSet<>();

        for (int x = 0; x < gameBoard.length ; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < gameBoard[0].length; y++) {
                //note that array indexes are [y][x] while point arguments are x,y
                if(gameBoard[y][x] != 0){
                    //use set to prevent duplicate elements. initialize it to allow for
                    //overlapping paths (paths that contain some shared points)
                    Set<Point> checkedPoints = new HashSet<>();
                    //set the origin of a potential new path
                    ArrayList<Point> potentialPath = new ArrayList<>();
                    Point origin = new Point (x,y);
                    if(checkedPoints.add(origin)) { //add returns false if duplicate
                        potentialPath.add(origin);
                        potentialPath = findPath(gameBoard, x, y, potentialPath, checkedPoints);
                        if (potentialPath != null) {
                            paths.add(new Path(potentialPath, gameBoard[y][x]));

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return paths;
    }

    private static ArrayList<Point> findPath(int[][] gameBoard, int x, int y,
                                ArrayList<Point> path, Set<Point> checkedPoints){

        int color = gameBoard[y][x]; //no need for color as argument. get from stone

        for(Neighbor neighbor : Neighbor.values()) {

            int neighborX = x + neighbor.x,   neighborY = y + neighbor.y;

            // avoid ArrayIndexOutOfBounds
            //todo: refactor to method isValidAddress(x,y,maxX, maxY)
            if((neighborX < 0) || ( neighborY < 0) || (neighborY >= gameBoard.length)
                    || (neighborX >= gameBoard[0].length)) {
                continue;
            }

            // check if there's a stone that matches the current stone, we're scanning around
            if((gameBoard[neighborY][neighborX] != 0) && (gameBoard[neighborY][neighborX] == color)){

                // found one
                Point nextStone = new Point(neighborX,neighborY);

                // is the point we just found the origin of the path ?
                if(nextStone.equals(path.get(0)) && (path.size() > MIN_PATH_LENGTH)) {
                    path.add(nextStone); //do you want it in path twice ?
                    //checkedPoints.add(nextStone); //if added to path before, it is already in checkedPoints
                    return path;
                }
                // otherwise if it's already part of the path ignore it
                if (path.contains(nextStone)) {
                    continue;
                }
                // else add it to the path and keep going
                path.add(nextStone);
                checkedPoints.add(nextStone);

                // recurse on the next stone in the path
                ArrayList<Point> newPath = findPath(gameBoard, neighborX, neighborY, path, checkedPoints);
                if (newPath == null){
                    // didn't find a way to continue, so backtrack
                    path.remove(path.size()-1);
                } else {
                    // we have a completed path to return
                    return newPath;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}

class Path {

    private ArrayList<Point> coordinateList;
    private int color;

    Path(ArrayList<Point> coordinatePath, int color){
        coordinateList = coordinatePath;
        this.color = color;
    }

    int getColor() { return color; }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return coordinateList.toString();
    }

    List<Point> getPoints() { return coordinateList; }
    int size() { return coordinateList.size(); }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object p){

        if (p == this) { return true; }
        if (p == null) { return false;}
        if (!(p instanceof Path)) {return false; }
        Path path = (Path)p;

        return getPoints().containsAll(path.getPoints())
                    && path.getPoints().containsAll(getPoints());
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I edited my question adding Stone.java class. However, is java.awt lib supported in android?

Comment: I don't know about Android. You can simply use different point class. I hope `Stone` class will help others. I had to do without it.

Comment: I added those classes, hope it will be of help. Going to test your answer

Comment: I guess you should be interested to Android programming, it's a lot of fun   youand as already have a strong Java knowledge, you can only be better at it.

Comment: One day I might (0:  Don't expect the code I posted to work, as I could not realy debug it. Just see if there are things in it you can borrow for your code.

Comment: The actual code works (mine), but fails the most times and I've noticed a performance issue, the game board becomes irresponsive. I can host the project somewhere so that you can have a better look?

Comment: Still, but you'd need to run android to be able to test even though it is an MVCe!

Comment: Again : mcve is first of all a tool for you. In addition it may help you get better help.

Comment: I was just talking about you. Thanks for the advice, I will try in the future.

Comment: See this [repo](https://bitbucket.org/c0derepo/pha/src/master/). I added a class called Simulate which runs your test data. It may be of help.

Comment: By the way, instead of using `ìnt[][]`, why not use Point class ?

Comment: You could. `int[][]` is simpler to initialize because default value is 0, so you have to initialize only non-zero values.

Comment: I'm getting access denied on the repo

Comment: I mean you didn't grant me write access, I can only clone it, not able to make Pull Requests

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178067/discussion-between-krul-and-c0der).